# Intuition for the Cone Lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, rational-numbers, convex-cone

> ***The Cone Lemma***.
> If a system of homogenous linear equations with integer coefficients has a
> *positive real* solution, then it also has a *positive integer* solution.

This is proved in *Proofs from THE BOOK*, 6th edition, p.70.
I don't find the proof easy to understand, and I wonder if anyone can
offer some intuition on why the lemma holds.

For example, does it still hold if the two instances of "positive" are removed?
What role does the homogenous assumption play?

Comment: if any integer linear equation =0 has a solution  vector it must be rational  you can take any multiple  of it, so here the common denominator and it is also a solution.

Comment: @trula: Thanks! May I ask: Why must the solution vector be rational?

Comment: otherwise you have no common denominator, and how would you get not rational solutions from linear equations with whole numbers?

Comment: Can you not conclude that by converting the matrix to reduced row echelon form?

Comment: an essentially analytic proof: consider $A \in \mathbb Q^{m\times n}$ and create a basis matrix $\mathbf B$ for $\ker A$.  Now change the field so $A \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and conclude $\mathbf B$ is still a basis for $\ker A$ (why?). You have positive $\mathbf x \in \ker A$, so $\mathbf x = \mathbf B\mathbf y$.  Since rationals are dense in reals there is a sequence $\mathbf y_k \in \mathbb Q^n$ such that $\mathbf y_k\to \mathbf y$ and $\mathbf x_k=\mathbf B\mathbf y_k$ so by continuity $\mathbf x_k$ is positive for $k$ large enough -- then clear denominators.